# Textviews are not showing on real device

Tags: android, textview, sensors

[When app works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Ua8.jpg)

[When app not shows textviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScPkL.jpg)(its finding a sensor. When cant find, giving info on textview like 'didnt found')

I created a pedometer app. It was working well on my emulator and my own android device. But when ı publish that app my friends said textviews are invisible. I examined that problem in code but didnt found a problem. Textviews are getting their text from sensor. Writing steps and calories, after some calculating. Why that problem showed up? What is the source of this problem? Why is this happening?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.mbkdev.fragments.CountStepFragment"
android:background="#211D44"
><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >



<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnstop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedbtn"
    android:text="Durdur"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#EBE9F1"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.781"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.184" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnstart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedbtn"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Başlat"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#EBE9F1"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnstop"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.472"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.184" /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtStepCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#48B9AC"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtStepCount"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColor="#48B9AC"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Hedef: 10.000"
    />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"
    android:rotation="-90"
    tools:progress="60" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progress_circular"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/cal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"



        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/distance"
        android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"

        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/steps"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
       />






</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/txtlinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progress_circular"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"

    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcalori_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Kalori: "
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#48B9AC"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtdistanceinfo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtdistanceinfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="#48B9AC"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Mesafe: "
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtstepinfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:textColor="#48B9AC"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtdistanceinfo"
        android:text="Adım: "
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />



</LinearLayout>
```

My StepCounterFragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_count_step,container,false);

    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);



    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_count_step, container, false);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtStepCount);
    txtstepinfo = view.findViewById(R.id.txtstepinfo);
    txtcalinfo = view.findViewById(R.id.txtcalori_info);
    txtDistanceinfo = view.findViewById(R.id.txtdistanceinfo);


    btnStart =  view.findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
    btnStop =    view.findViewById(R.id.btnstop);
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);
    progressBar.setMax(10000);
    
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService();
        }
    });
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), StepCountService.class));
        }
    });

    sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) != null){
        stepCounter = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        isCounterSensorPresent = true;
    }
    else{
        textView.setText("Bulunamadı");
        isCounterSensorPresent = false ;
    }






    System.out.println(stepCount);


    return view;
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor == stepCounter){
        stepCount = (int) sensorEvent.values[0];
        ////////////////
        saveSteps();
        resetStep();

        int stepNumb = sharedPreferences.getInt("step",0);
        ////////////////
        progressBar.setProgress(stepNumb);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(stepNumb));
        txtstepinfo.setText("Adım: " +  String.valueOf(stepNumb) );
        ///////////
        progressBar.setProgress(stepNumb);
        Log.i("sda",String.valueOf(stepCount));
        /////////////////////
        txtcalinfo.setText("Kalori: "+calculateCalori(stepNumb));
        txtDistanceinfo.setText("Mesafe: "+calculateDistance(stepNumb));

    }

}
```

Comment: Some devices can see the texts. Is that about sensor?

Comment: What is the device you are using to test this? most devices especially the low-mid tier ones will not have a barometer sensor, so your text view is visible but not getting any text to display

Comment: Yes, possible. But even lower ones detecting sensor. If the problem causing of sensor problem, how to fix this? I dont want to use gps. Is there any different way exist?

Comment: there is no such thing as lower ones detecting sensors, u need to read the hardware specs for each device to see if it can support this or not, from a similar case 1 year ago i had to remove the barometer feature cause the majority of phones do not have the sensor

Comment: Device has a sensor. If app can not find a sensor its writing 'sensor didnt found'. Also ı download a another app which using sensor. It was working well. I didnt get where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is the problem. I was forgetting the add user permissions.

I Added to the Manifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

onCreate Method:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
    //ask for permission
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, PHYISCAL_ACTIVITY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not one of programmatic issue and could be your listview went up to bottom on screen. You could research How to develop an android application for different device sizes. Visit here https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: I tried that but didnt work too. App detects sensors. So its not about sensors. Something wrong at my setText i think. But ı dont know what's the problem.